# Capturar valor dentro da string

Tags: php

Bom tenho um variável que recebe um string, com o nome da cidade e pode acontecer de ter o bairro dentro de parênteses. Preciso separa isso em 2 variáveis.

Exemplo 1:

```
$cidade = "BOA ESPERANÇA";
```

Retorno que eu preciso.

```
$nome_cidade = "BOA ESPERANÇA";
$bairro = null;
```

Exemplo 2:

```
$cidade = "BOA ESPERANÇA (CENTRO)";
```

Retorno que eu preciso.

```
$nome_cidade = "BOA ESPERANÇA";
$bairro = "CENTRO";
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Expressão regular é uma solução.

Comment: acredito que falte mais informações na pergunta Hugo, quais as possiveis variações do nome da cidade? será sempre o nome seguido do centro entre parenteses?

Comment: E se somente abrir o parentese, mas não fechá-lo, deve ser considerado como bairro, tal como em `"BOA ESPERANÇA (CENTRO"`?

Comment: Primeiro de tudo você precisa encontrar o padrão regular em todas as ocorrências, pois qualquer solução que apareça servirá apenas para os exemplos apresentados, o que aparentemente não representa o problema como um todo.

Comment: @RFL o bairro sempre vai vir dentro de parênteses, porém pode ocorrer de não vir o bairro logo não terá os parênteses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça da seguinte maneira:

```php
<?php
  $cidade = "CIDADE (BAIRRO)";
  $options = explode("(", $cidade);

  if(isset($options[1])) $bairro = str_replace(")","",$options[1]);
  else $bairro = null;
  $nome_cidade = str_replace(" ","",$options[0]);

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/([^\(]+)\(?([^\)]+)?\)?/
```

1. `([^\(]+)`, cria um grupo de captura para qualquer caractere diferente de `(`;
2. `\(?`, define o caractere literal `(` como opcional;
3. `([^\)]+)`, cria um grupo de captura para qualquer caractere diferente de `)`;
4. `\)?`, define o caractere literal `)` como opcional;

Assim:

```
function get_cidade_bairro($nome)
{
    if (preg_match('/([^\(]+)\(?([^\)]+)?\)?/', $nome, $matches)) {
        return [
            'cidade' => $matches[1],
            'bairro' => $matches[2] ?? null
        ];
    }

    return null;
}


$tests = [
    "BOA ESPERANÇA",
    "BOA ESPERANÇA (CENTRO)"
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    var_export( get_cidade_bairro($test) );
}
```

A saída é:

```
array (
  'cidade' => 'BOA ESPERANÇA',
  'bairro' => NULL,
)

array (
  'cidade' => 'BOA ESPERANÇA ',
  'bairro' => 'CENTRO',
)
```